# Will Community review re-open votes by OP on Single-handedly closed question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, closed-questions, dupehammer

Lets take an example of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427870/is-there-any-alternatives-of-letterspacing-attribute-for-edittext-in-api-level-2) which was asked a day before. The question was frequently marked as duplicate by single hand. Actually the question was not duplicate, It was the case of two attributes of EditText in android, one was `android:textScaleX` and another was `android:letterSpacing`.

I frequently edited my question with screenshot of results using both attribute to prove that these are not same and my question is not duplicate and voted to re-open the question. The natural behavior in stack overflow is no one will view the question after seeing the duplicate tag trailed in the title even we also don't.

Even if the question is re-opened now, it has gone below in stack of questions and I think this will not receive any further attention.

**1. Should I have to bounty this question spending my own hard-earned reputation now to get attention if question is re-opened ? OR I have to copy all question and ask it by pasting as new ?**

**2. Why our single vote on re-opening the question won't be reviewed by community, even after we showed the full proof ?**

Comment: If you edit the post, it already goes into a queue to be reviewed by people who can vote to reopen it.

Comment: @resueman thanks for the info but will people see it on homepage after re-opening ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna Yes.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna You certainly can; there's no information here not found in the FAQ/help center, but that's up to you.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna For your information, the question is now reopened. 5 Members of the community cast reopen votes, so its open again.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "frequently". Your question was closed only once.

Answer (score 3):

> **1. Should I have to bounty this question spending my own hard-earned reputation now to get attention if question is re-opened ? OR I have to copy all question and ask it by pasting as new ?**

Probably yes. Or try to improve your question and bumping it up to the active questions view. Asking a new question doesn't seem to be the right action.

> **2. Why our single vote on re-opening the question won't be reviewed by community, even after we showed the full proof ?**

Reopening votes actually **are reviewed**, but there's no guarantee that process is fast.

You should take care to make your question as clear and self contained in first place.